# How to create or alter database in slave in Postgresql 9.3?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I tried replication in postgres 9.3, and successfully implemented it.
After that i am unable to create new database in slave. It says "cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction." Does this mean i cannot create or alter database in slave?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The slave is in read-only mode and all changes you want to make should be done on the master server that propagates it to its slaves. Making the slave read-write would defeat the purpose of the replication (if we are not considering master-master or multi-master replication)